# Cleaning text data for sentiment analysis and bag-of-words

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am currently working ina project to test and train data for sentiment analysis. Since, i have encounter a problem which relate to re.sub() and i am unable to figure it out how to solve that. My codes are as below:

```
import re def preprocessor(text):
    text = re.sub(r"<[^>]*>", "",  text) # removes all the html markup
    emoticons = re.findall('(?::|;|= )(?:-)?(?:\)|\(|D|P)', text)
    # removed all the non word charecter and convert them into lower case
    text = (re.sub(r'[\W]+', '', text.lower()) + ''.join(emoticons).replace('-', ''))
    return text
```

As you can see the function is working fine, no exception raised. However, as i want to print the text to see if it produce my desire result, I get the following output:

```
preprocessor(df.loc[0, 'review'][-50:])` 



'isseventitlebrazilnotavailable'
```

Whereas my desire output should be:

```
'is seven title brazil not available'
```

I kind of guess my re.sub() is removing all whitespace but I can not figure it out how to fix that.

An answer would be appreciatable.

N.B:
I would like to clean string from as follows: as an example:
from
'is seven.
Title (Brazil): Not Available'
to

```
'is seven title brazil not available'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
text = 'is seven.<br /><br />Title (Brazil): Not  Available' 
## remove tags
text = re.sub(r"<.*?>", " ",  text)
## sub with blank
text = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9\s+]', '', text)
print(text)
```

output:

`'is seven  Title Brazil Not Available'`

Comment: Thanks Narendra, I would like to clean text like following 'is seven.<br /><br />Title (Brazil): Not Available'

Comment: @shaara You can upvote my answer if it helps you. What is your expected output for `'is seven.<br /><br />Title (Brazil): Not Available' ` text?

Comment: have edited my recent post, if you can have a look and tell me more precisely please

Comment: @shaara, I have updated my solution, that works exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `\W` in your regex, that includes the whitespace characters as well. Those are also being replaced by an empty string in your case. To demonstrate, here is a snippet of code,

```
import re

text = "This is my Text"
text1 = re.sub(r'[\W]+', '', text.lower())
text2 = re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z0-9_\s]+', '', text.lower())

print(text1)
print(text2)
```

if you check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]` is actually equivalent to `\W`. You would need to add the whitespace regex symbol (`\s`) in that list if you do not want them to be replaced by an empty string (as done in the example above for `text2`).